# pgadmin4- missing csv option

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have problem. After upgrade my server I have too change pgAdmin to version 4 v2.0, and now I can't change the separator ext.
I don't have option to change csv.
My options : 
[image]

In manual they have option to change csv.
[image: enter image description]

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you mentioned are [committed recently](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2781) in the code base and will be available in next public release of pgAdmin4, I would suggest you try these options when the new version is available.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you recommend another program?

Comment: Check: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/export-postgresql-table-to-csv-file/ & for more options https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html